# How to let bash subshell to inherit parent's set options?

Tags: linux, bash

Let’s say I do `set -x` in a script “a.sh”, and it invokes another script “b.sh”.

Is it possible to let “b.sh” inherit the `-x` option from “a.sh”?

Comment: Use `.` or `source` to invoke `b.sh`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
export SHELLOPTS
```

for example:

```
echo date > b
chmod +x b
```

without the export, we only see the commands in `./a` when it calls `./b`:

```
$ echo ./b > a
$ bash -xv a

./a
+ ./b
Sun Dec 29 21:34:14 EST 2013
```

but if we export SHELLOPTS, we see the commands in `./a` and `./b`

```
$ echo "export SHELLOPTS; ./b" > a
$ bash -xv a

./a
+ ./b  date
++ date   
Sun Dec 29 21:34:36 EST 2013
```

Comment: This is a little too confusing for me

Answer (score 4):

Since `-x` is not inherited by subshells, you need to be a bit more explicit. You can test when `-x` is used with the `$-` special parameter.

```
if [[ $- = *x* ]]; then
    # Set the option, then *source* the script, in a subshell
    ( set -x; . b.sh )
else
    # Simply run the script; subshell automatically created.
    ./b.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

They would be incorporated in script b if script b [sources](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) script a. Which may or may not solve your problem for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then b wouldn't be a subshell. Do you know a way when you execute it as a command rather than sourcing it?

Comment: @dspjm It cannot happen within a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Like @devnull said you can use `.` operation in your script.

In a.sh

`. SETVALUES`

In b.sh

`. SETVALUES`

In SETVALUES

`set -x`

Where ever you invoke SETVALUES, those values will be set in that sub shell.